# Calling SignalR via AWS Websockets Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, signalr

This may not be possible, but I thought that I would at least ask.

In AWS API Gateway for Websockets, the gateway itself handles the connections. The backend ASP.NET Core application receives an event containing $connect/$disconnect and a connection id.

Is it possible to use the SignalR framework in this case?

There are (of course) other ways, but it would be great to be able to use SignalR.

Suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Have you figured it out how to use SignalR with AWS? I am having the same problem...

Comment: Hi Vlad, nothing yet. I have asked the Amazon team https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/444 and also asked the DotNet Core SignalR team https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9522#issuecomment-484792540

It does not look very hopeful at this point.

Comment: Did you ever find out a way?